# Can someone provide an example of how javac's -implicit option works?

Tags: java, compiler-options

At the shell command prompt, if I type in `javac -help`, it tells me that the `-implicit` option specifies "... whether or not to generate class files for implicitly referenced files".  There are two options that go with `-implicit:` `none` or `class`.

Firstly, what's the difference between using `-implicit:none` and not using the -`implicit` option?

Secondly, regarding my question title, I was hoping that an example provided would help me to understand what an implicitly referenced file was.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have it described quite well in the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCJJJAJ).

The answer to your first question is quite simple. Not using the `-implicit` option is almost like using `-implicit:class` (which is the default value of the option), but by explicitly using the option you suppress certain warning:

> The compiler might not discover the need for some type information
>   until after annotation processing completes. When the type information
>   is found in a source file and no `-implicit` option is specified, the
>   compiler gives a warning that the file is being compiled without being
>   subject to annotation processing. To disable the warning, either
>   specify the file on the command line (so that it will be subject to
>   annotation processing) or use the `-implicit` option to specify whether
>   or not class files should be generated for such source files.

Now your second question. As the documentation states:

> To compile a source file, the compiler often needs information about a
>   type, but the type definition is not in the source files specified on
>   the command line. The compiler needs type information for every class
>   or interface used, extended, or implemented in the source file. This
>   includes classes and interfaces not explicitly mentioned in the source
>   file, but that provide information through inheritance.
>
> For example, when you create a subclass java.applet.Applet, you are
>   also using the ancestor classes of Applet: `java.awt.Panel`,
>   `java.awt.Container`, `java.awt.Component`, and `java.lang.Object`.

Let's have three classes in three files: Main, ImplicitClass, BaseImplicitClass.

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImplicitClass ec = new ImplicitClass();
        System.out.println(ec.getClass());
    }
}
```

ImplicitClass.java:

```
public class ImplicitClass extends BaseImplicitClass {
}
```

BaseImplicitClass.java:

```
public class BaseImplicitClass {
}
```

When you compile them from command line like this:

```
javac -cp . -implicit:class Main.java
```

or

```
javac -cp . Main.java
```

all the three *.class files are created.

When you compile it

```
javac -cp . -implicit:none Main.java
```

only Main.class is created.

When you compile it

```
javac -cp . -implicit:none Main.java ImplicitClass.java
```

two *.class files are created, `Main.class` and `ImplicitClass.class` (the `ImplicitClass` has now become explicit because it has been explicitly passed to the compiler), but not `BaseImplicitClass.class` as this class is needed, but is implicit.